# Converting Aerial file

Tags: utm

I am mapping utilities for a small town in Iowa. I have shapefiles of my water, gas and sewer lines, fire hydrants, ect. I also have an aerial view of the town that was taken in state plane. When I bring that aerial file into the project I cannot see any of my utilities that I have already set up. The shapefiles are set to NAD83/UTM Zone 15N EPSG:26915.

I am just learning the software.

Comment: What software: QGIS, ArcGIS, or something else?

Comment: Need to know what software you are using view/edit/import/display the shapefiles

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely basic, but if you are new to the software perhaps...:

Is the aerial photography simply overlaying the other features? Try to move it to the bottom of the table of contents list.  This would apply to QGIS and ESRI products alike as each feature added is generally place on top of the last features.

Good way to avoid this without moving everything around all the time is to add the large features to the map first, so Aerial then Polygon features, then line features, and lastly points...

Or if you're going to be analyzing overlapping features, set a transparency in the layer properties so you can view features that lay underneath the opaque layer...

Hope this helps!